# how to filter link url http:// and www with preg replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i made some function using preg_replace. the code is to get the preview of it.

i made this code

```
$strings     = htmlspecialchars_uni($thread['soc_instagram']);
$searchs     = array('~(?:https://instagram\.com/p/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+?:]+)~');
$replaces    = array('https://instagram.com/p/$1/media/?size=l');  
$soc_instagram = preg_replace($searchs,$replaces,$strings);
```

the code work perfect if i post an instagram with this url https://instagram.com/p/BarUcqwht_u

and it will produce code

```
https://instagram.com/p/BaQsAubg6H3/media/?size=l
```

but the problem is when i try to add WWW in the url, something like this https://www.instagram.com/p/BarUcqwht_u the code will produce error string

the result will be like this

```
https://instagram.com/p/https:/media/?size=l//https://instagram.com/p/www/media/?size=l.https://instagram.com/p/instagram/media/?size=l.https://instagram.com/p/com/media/?size=l/https://instagram.com/p/p/media/?size=l/https://instagram.com/p/BarUcqwht_u/media/?size=l/
```

i try to add WWW in my preg_replace code but the result will be like this

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/https:/media/?size=l//https://www.instagram.com/p/instagram/media/?size=l.https://www.instagram.com/p/com/media/?size=l/https://www.instagram.com/p/p/media/?size=l/https://www.instagram.com/p/BaQsAubg6H3/media/?size=l
```

any help will be nice, thanks

Comment: Sooo.... You need to check if there is one or zero occurrences of (www)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `www.` after the protocol and make it optional. `preg_replace` also doesn't require arrays, strings work fine.

```
$strings     = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BarUcqwht_u';
$searchs     = '~(?:https://(?:www\.)?instagram\.com/p/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+?:]+)~';
$replaces    = 'https://instagram.com/p/$1/media/?size=l';
$soc_instagram = preg_replace($searchs,$replaces,$strings); 
echo $soc_instagram;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/WSors

What your current implementation does is replaces characters not listed in your character class with the URL. See https://regex101.com/r/PXb2h1/2/ for a visual representation.